# Calculate the string length in sed

Tags: regex, sed

I was forced to calculate the string length in `sed`. The string is always a nonempty sequence of `a`'s.

```
sed -n ':c /a/! be; s/^a/1/; s/0a/1/; s/1a/2/; s/2a/3/; s/3a/4/; s/4a/5/; s/5a/6/; s/6a/7/; s/7a/8/; s/8a/9/; s/9a/a0/; /a/ bc; :e p'
```

It's quite long :) So now I wonder if it is possible to rewrite this script more concisely using the `y` or [other sed command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/sed-commands-list.html#sed-commands-list)?

I know that it is better to use awk or another tool. However, this is not a question here.

Note that the sed script basically simulates [decadic full adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)).

Comment: `y` certainly would not work for this; it replaces all occurrences of one character with another.

Comment: Actually this is pretty succinct for a task that only hardcore masochists would even attempt to solve with `sed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's cheating but:

```
sed 's/.//;s/./\n/g'|sed -n '$='
```

You can certainly shorten your existing version to:

```
sed -n ':c s/^a/1/; s/0a/1/; s/1a/2/; s/2a/3/; s/3a/4/; s/4a/5/; s/5a/6/; s/6a/7/; s/7a/8/; s/8a/9/; s/9a/a0/; tc; p'
```

Turns out using `y///` **is** possible but I think it only shaves off a few characters, and `\u` is not portable:

```
sed -n '
:c;
s/^a/c/;
s/\([b-j]\)a/\u\1/;
y/BCDEFGHIJ/cdefghijk/;
s/ka/ab/;
tc;
y/bcdefghijk/0123456789/;
p
'
```

Comment: Nice :) The problem with the first solution is that the sed command should be invoked on multiple-line inputs. The last solution is clever (!) but quite complicated. A little while ago I found [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Increment-a-number.html#Increment-a-number). In the light of that, I believe that this problem cannot be easily solved in sed :(